# Does Mtt 26:24 hint at the possibility of pre-natal existence of a person's soul?

Tags: matthew, soul

We see Jesus predicting his death in Mtt 26:24 (NRSVCE ):

> The Son of man goes as it is written of him, but woe to that man by
> whom the Son of man is betrayed! It would have been better for that
> man if he had not been born.”

Let us look at the prospects of Judas not having been born. That would not deter the human incarnation and redemptive mission of Son of God from happening. On the other side, Judas not born would be Judas not in existence. But then, how is not being in existence beneficial to the person? Is it that a person's soul pre-exists his/ her conception and foetal life, the latter being the stage of preparation for ' birth into the world? In other words, did Judas have a soul that existed even before his conception?

My question therefore, is: **Does Matt 26:24 hint at the possibility of pre-natal existence of a person's soul?**

Answer (score 1):

Matthew 26:24 may hint at the pre-natal existence of a man's soul or spirit, but another verse that is more definitive is Jeremiah 1:5.

Jeremiah 1:5

> Before I formed thee in the belly I knew thee; and before thou camest forth out of the womb I sanctified thee, and I ordained thee a prophet unto the nation's.

Comment: That is not about pre-natal existence and far less about pre-natal prophetic ordination of Jeremiah, for otherwise Jeremiah would have answered: "Dear Lord, why do you tell me things I know very well, for I know you have ordained me as a prophet before I was born, I remember that solemn moment; but how strange it that you, o Lord, ordain now me again as a prophet, why? Was not my first ordination in pre-natal life enough, or did I lapse from the prophetship and now I need to be reordained?" But Jeremiah does not ask such weird questions, does he?

Comment: I was about to agree with you, about the possibility of it not being about pre-natal existence. But if not about that, would it not have to be prophetic?

Comment: Simply it is that God’s nature and knowledge is 100% devoid of time; therefore He knows those events that are future to us in His eternal “now”. Thus, it is not that He ordained unborn soul of Jeremiah, say, 1000 years after his soul’s creation out of nothing and, say, 2087 years before his historical birth, - NO! It is as it were He tells Jeremiah: “Before you were born historically, I already knew the entirety of your life, for my being and knowledge are eternal and thus even all temporal, historical events I, the omniscient God, know eternally, in My eternal “now””.

Comment: That's what I was meaning of being prophetic.

Answer (score 0):

If my lamb is left unattended on a field and it is devoured by a hungry wolf, and I say: "Poor lamb, would be better for it if it was not born", does it mean that I assume that this lamb was there before its birth? But then this sentence looses its sense, because if there was a pre-existent lamb, then there would also be pre-existent wolf there in a pre-existent field and this pre-existent wolf would have devoured the poor pre-existent lamb for satisfying his pre-existent hunger.

Similarly, if Judas existed before with all the apostles and Jesus, then he could also betray his pre-existent Teacher just like he betrayed Him while in existence and deliver Him to pre-existent Sanhedrin and pre-existent Pontius Pilate - a pre-existent pre-administrator of pre-Roman pre-Empire.

Comment: Levan, it looks like you have gone a mile too far from the question, which is not about a previous life of Judas . If we believe that his soul outlived his body, we may also doubt if the soul had been there before he took birth.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan Souls of the deceased people live, have memory, will, and they pray to God, even those souls that are in hell pray for their beloved on earth, as the parable about the rich man says, for this rich man is in hell and still cares for his yet living brethren. But pre-birth souls cannot exist for they would lack memory, will, consiousness, and as such, would not exist. Imagine an absurdity: a deceased man’s  soul meets an unborn man’s soul, what kind of dialogue can be between them? None, for unborn soul would be 100% nob-communicable.

Comment: Helen Keller who was both blind and deaf, famously said : " In the next life, I can see and hear ! "  The qualities of soul do not commensurate with the qualities of the body it dwells in.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan H Keller had consciousness, anything without consciousness is either mineral, or plant

Comment: @ Levan Gigineishvili If we agree that spirits are eternal, either in Heaven or he'll, whose to say they don't go backwards as well as foreward according to terrestrial time. Aren't you assuming a spirit begins a t conception. Since God can divide spirit from soul, maybe there was a " brain wipe" in the process. I realize spirit and soul are not physical and have a brain. I am just using a figure of speech. Truth is God did not give us much to go on here.

Comment: @RHPclass79 But we don’t agree that souls are eternal and uncreated, no, that will be Platonism, not Christianity. You can pray to St George or even asked your blessed deceased grandfather to supplicate for you to God, but nobody can ask an unborn soul anything for no such unborn soul exists. Angels are intelligent souls, but they do not incarnate, they never become humans in history.

Comment: @ Levan Gigineishvili Don't get me wrong. I agree with you doctrinally, but I am trying to stick to the OP's original posted question and quoted verse. I think he has a point. How could it be better for Judas, if he had never existed. Of course your answer will be " to never exist is better than to exist and suffer the punishment of hell".

Comment: @ Levan Gigineishvili Maybe Jesus' example of the millstone about someone's neck and being cast into the sea , of one that harms a little child, is proof of your point.

Comment: @RHPclass79 “My poor lamb was left unattended on field and eaten by avaricious wolf! Oh, poor thing, would be better for it if it was not born!” Do I imply in any way that this poor lamb preexisted its birth? No, no and thousand times no!

Comment: @RHPclass79 “My poor lamb was left unattended on field and eaten by avaricious wolf! Oh, poor thing, would be better for it if it was not born!” Do I imply in any way that this poor lamb preexisted its birth? No, no and thousand times no!

Comment: I think you are comparing Judases to lambs here. Kind of like apples to oranges. They are both fruit. Even when someone agrees with you, you still kill the poor lamb.intersting.

Comment: @RHPclass79 I simply say that it is not “apple&oranges” thing at all, it is a literary trope called hyperbole, that’s how language works. “I haven’t seen you for ages” does not mean that guys lived more than two hundred years, for instance.

Comment: @Levan Gigineishviili. Looking forward to some future discussions with you on topics less obtuse than this. Maybe e= mc2 or something. I am getting that prompt on " chat ". I do appreciate your comments as they are in line with excepted theological doctrine. Catch you later. Figure of speech!

Comment: @RHPclass79 Fine, let us cross swords on other, more interesting issues. Figure of speech here also)

Comment: To both RHPclass79 and Levan: I wish I did not ask this Question on BHSE ! But I am happy I was born to witness the ' fight' , because someone else would have asked the Question . Personally I feel that Jesus was very sad in speaking of Judas and that  figures of speech would be the last thing in his mind.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan When Job cursed the day of his birth (Job 3:1), he did not curse transition from a better condition of pre-natal life to a worse condition of post-natal life, for there is no pre-natal life. Lord uses figures of speech, not infrequently. When He calls Herod a “fox” (Luke 13:32), does He mean that a fox dressed itself in a human body and features now as Herod? No, it’s a figure of speech. Similarly, He does not mean here that it was better for Judas’ soul to remain among angels than to gain a human body and enter human history.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan,Levan Gigineishvili: I am grinning from ear to ear. The biggest problem I have is typing in both of your screen names. Couldn't y'all just use Jo or Lev.

Comment: RHPclass79, you are using a fictitious name in BHSE, are you not ? What I have in the forum is my civil name in full . Call me Sebastian, which is my Baptismal Name.